# Exception Enumerating SQL Server Instances with SMO WMI ManagedComputer

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008, powershell, wmi, sql-server

I'm trying to use the SMO WMI API/objects in PowerShell 2.0 on Windows 7 with SQL Server 2008 R2 installed to get a list of SQL Server instances on the local computer using the [Managed Comuter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.wmi.managedcomputer.aspx) object.  However, I'm getting exceptions after I instantiate the objects when I try to access any data on them.  I'm running PowerShell as an administrator.

```
$computer = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.WMI.ManagedComputer ($env:computername)
$computer.ServerInstances
```

Results in this error:

> The following exception was thrown when trying to enumerate the collection: "An exception occurred in SMO while trying to manage a service.".
>   At line:1 char:89
>   + (New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.WMI.ManagedComputer ($env:computername)). <<<< ServerInstances
>      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionInGetEnumerator

Is there some service I have to enable to get this to work?  The WMI service is running.  Is there some other setting I need?  *Why can't I enumerate SQL Server instances?*

Comment: Do you load the Assembly for SQL WMI Management? `[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SQLWMIManagement')` ?

Comment: I can also note that running that command on my Windows 8.1 machine with two named instances running, shows the `ServerInstances` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this code as administrator? Access to WMI requires WMI privileges. However, there is an alternate method I use. I documented that here: http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/04/24/pstip-enumerate-all-sql-server-instances-in-a-network/

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoApplication]::EnumAvailableSqlServers("MyDBServer")
```

Comment: I've updated my question to note that I am running as an administrator.

Comment: That's the workaround I tried. Unfortunately, my script also does some other work with SMO.WMI, and I'm getting similar problems. I really need to get the WMI stuff working.